# R: 'vectorizing' a triple loop

Tags: r, sum, vectorization, apply, sapply

I've written a piece of code in R that computes a double sum of the so called rank statistics.

I need to repeat the computation of Q minimum 1000 times but with 3 loops inside, it takes a quite long time to do it just once.

Here is my code:

```
#u, a - real numbers
l <- function(u, a) {
  -sqrt((1-a)/a)*I(u>=0 & u<a) + sqrt(a/(1-a))*I(u>=a & u<=1)
}


# r,s - real number, R,S - vectors of real numbers (equal lengths)
L<-function(r, s, R, S) {
  n<-length(R)
  x<-0
  for (i in 1:n) {
    x<-x+l(R[i]/(n+1),r) * l(S[i]/(n+1),s)
  }
  1/sqrt(n)*x
}

# r, s, X, Y - vectors of real numbers; X and Y must be equally long
Q<-function(r,s,X,Y) {
  n<-length(X)
  R<-rank(X)
  S<-rank(Y)
  q<-0
  for (j in 1:length(r)) {
    for (k in 1:length(s)) {
      q<-q+L(r[j],s[k],R,S)^2

    }
  } 
  q
}
```

I tried to transform my functions using sapply and apply, but then the first function failed because the sizes of r and s may not be equal (nor should the lengths of r, s be equal to the length of X (or Y)).

Is there any way to produce a function L which takes 4 vectors and produces a matrix, so that I get rid of the loops?

Thanks in advance!

//Edit:

I've written an alternative function using mapply:

```
Q1<-function(r,s,X,Y) {
  n<-length(X)
  R<-rank(X)
  S<-rank(Y)
  rs <- expand.grid(r,s)
  q<-do.call(mapply, c(function(r,s) L(r,s,R=R,S=S)^2, unname(rs)))
  sum(q)
}
```

but it seems to be even slower.

Comment: Probably faster to use `L(r[j],s[k],R,S)^2` rather than calling the L function twice to do: `L(r[j],s[k],R,S)*L(r[j],s[k],R,S)`. It's also faster to predimension vectors ans assign into locations than to concatenate.

Comment: Well, indeed - using ^2 instead of multiplying helped, it goes almost 2 times faster now, thanks a lot.
I also replaced concatenation with cumulative summation in both functions, it saved ca. 0.1 s.
Still wondering if there's a way to omit the loops (provided it takes less time indeed), though.

Comment: Not sure you understood the suggestion to pre-dimension. You should edit your code to show what you did.

Comment: I think I did (you meant declaring vectors of specified lengths and then filling them with values, didn't you?) but I just tried something which I thought will be faster (maybe I'm wrong).
I edited my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to generate all of the values of L(.) for varying values of `r` and `s`, a loop-less method might be:

```
  rs <- expand.grid(r=r,s=s); rm(r); rm(s)
  #edit
  rs$qrs <- with(rs, L(r, s, R, S)^2 )
  q <- sum(rs$qrs)
```

I'm not convinced this will be faster. There is a widespread but erroneous notion that loops in R are inefficient. Most of the gains in efficiency will come from simplifying the inner functions.

```
    >  set.seed(123)
>    r <- runif(4)
>    s <- runif(3)
>    rs <- expand.grid(r=r,s=s)
> rs
           r         s
1  0.2875775 0.9404673
2  0.7883051 0.9404673
3  0.4089769 0.9404673
4  0.8830174 0.9404673
5  0.2875775 0.0455565
6  0.7883051 0.0455565
7  0.4089769 0.0455565
8  0.8830174 0.0455565
9  0.2875775 0.5281055
10 0.7883051 0.5281055
11 0.4089769 0.5281055
12 0.8830174 0.5281055
> rs$qrs <- with(rs, L(r, s, 1:10, 1:10)^2 )
>   q <- sum(rs$qrs)
> q
[1] 14.39009
> rs
           r         s          qrs
1  0.2875775 0.9404673 0.0004767998
2  0.7883051 0.9404673 0.0003911883
3  0.4089769 0.9404673 6.6571168565
4  0.8830174 0.9404673 0.0017673788
5  0.2875775 0.0455565 0.0004767998
6  0.7883051 0.0455565 0.0003911883
7  0.4089769 0.0455565 6.6571168565
8  0.8830174 0.0455565 0.0017673788
9  0.2875775 0.5281055 0.0004767998
10 0.7883051 0.5281055 0.0003911883
11 0.4089769 0.5281055 6.6571168565
12 0.8830174 0.5281055 0.0017673788
```

Comment: Isn't there a mistake in 
    rs$qrs <- L(r[j],s[k],R,S)^2 
? I don't quite know how to use expand.grid with a function, but if it is loop-less, we don't have any k's or j's anymore, do we?

Anyway, such an usage of L results in "object 'j' not found".

Comment: Right. Should have included `with(rs, )`

Comment: And taken out the indices.

Comment: Well, it works very fine as far as time is concerned (about 30 times faster for X,Y of length 100 and r,s of lengths 8,4 respectively), but I'm afraid the result is just wrong...

The Q and Q1 functions (to be seen in my first post) give the same results for a fixed input, the one proposed by you is different.
See for yourself for X=Y=rnorm(100) and r, s - any vectors of numbers within (0,1).

Are you sure this should be generating L(.) for all combinations of (r,s)?

Comment: It produces 32 numbers indeed, but they differ from what I get from the Q function. Does `with` work properly when the last 2 arguments of L, that is R and S, are vectors?

Comment: I'll post my test case. If this is wrong then you will have something to point to more specifically.

Comment: Every test case that meets the assumptions (that is: X and Y must have equal sizes and r, s are from (0,1)) should be OK. Q and Q1 work for your input and produce equal results every time.
I believe something must be "wrong" in the definition of L then. I mean, maybe it is not suitable for `with` in the form it is now...

Comment: The error was mine. I should have built rs using column names. The `rs` I built had columns "Var1" and "Var2".